# Determining the number of surfaces and boundaries *from* the number of vertices, edges and faces.

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology

Question:

Suppose that the number of vertices, the number of edges and the number of faces are given for a set of polyhedra (consisting of triangles only). Can the *number of polyhedra* and *number of boundaries* be determined from these parameters only? Is there an answer that enables cheap computation *or* one that shows that such an approach does not exist?

Background:

In the field of Mechanical engineering, Computer Aided Engineering (CAE) sometimes requires a 3D mesh of connected triangular elements to represent the geometry of e.g. machine components. However, these meshes may not always be 'watertight' or accidentally contain more that one component where a single component is expected, etcetera. The question is if there exists a computationally cheap function to analyze this, similar to the Euler–Poincaré characteristic. Approaches that I here consider computationally expensive are e.g. topology traversal using e.g. advancing front techniques.

Answer (score 0):

This document essentially explains how Mesh simplification can be done for CAE modelling. 
It also discusses about how to use the Euler characteristic from a topological standpoint

http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF3320/h03/undervisningsmateriale/lecture10.pdf

Comment: Great document for introducing the matter to non-specialists in an intuitive manner. However, the document does not contain an answer to the question.

Comment: It does contain methods for simplifying meshes as opposed to finding an algorithm, which even I am still looking for.